# How to generate a class diagram in Dart?

Tags: flutter, dart, class-diagram

Is there a tool to generate a diagram of Dart classes in a project?

Not necessarily a strict UML diagram, I just want to visually represent the hierarchy of existing modules and see how they are interconnected.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

I've found the [dcdg](https://pub.dev/packages/dcdg) package that is doing exactly what I want.

It generates [PlantUML](https://plantuml.com/) file which in order can be transformed into PNG or SVG image using PLantUML's [demo web server](http://www.plantuml.com/plantuml) or using other third-party tools.

Comment: How can I exclude dart and flutter native classes ? I would like to generate only my classes. Do you know how can I get it ?